# Copying Mobile Me Gallery photos into empty iPhoto

Tags: iphoto, mobileme

My hard drive died so I lost all of my data.  However, I'd uploaded all my photos to Mobile Me Gallery.  How do I bring them back from Mobile Me into my now empty iPhoto so they are restored back onto my Macbook Air?

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4702) KB article should tell you how to do it

Make sure that your MobileMe account is properly configured in Mac System Preferences and that you are using a broadband Internet connection.

Launch iPhoto and determine which version of iPhoto you are using by choosing `iPhoto > About iPhoto`.

If you use iPhoto '11 (version 9):

```
1 Open iPhoto.
2 Choose iPhoto > Preferences.
3 Click Accounts at the top of the preferences window and make sure that your MobileMe 
account is visible on the left. If not, add your account by clicking the plus sign 
and entering your MobileMe username and password.
4 Select your MobileMe account under the Web section of the iPhoto source list.
5 Double-click on each individual album in your Gallery and wait for any new photos
in the album to download to your computer.  A photo is completely downloaded when 
the word “pending” no longer appears on the bottom of the photo.
6 Once all photos have been downloaded you can drag and drop photos from each of your 
galleries to Photos in the left hand column to ensure that they are in your main iPhoto library.
```

If you use iPhoto ’08 (version 7) or iPhoto ’09 (version 8):

```
1 Open iPhoto.
2 Choose iPhoto > Preferences.
3 Click Web at the top of the preferences window. 
4 From the "Check for new published photos menu", choose Automatically 
and then click the Check Now button. Then, dismiss the window.
5 In the left hand pane of iPhoto, expand MobileMe Gallery and click on each album, one 
by one.  As you click each album, a spinning icon will indicate that iPhoto is checking 
MobileMe for any photos that have not yet been synced to your computer. If any photos 
are found, they will be downloaded automatically.
6 Once all photos have been downloaded you can drag and drop photos from each of your 
galleries to Photos in the left hand column to ensure that they are in your main 
iPhoto library.
```